# Very simple if statement is not working in Windows Forms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, if-statement

The code is simple:

```
namespace Textboxta10_karakterde_1_alt_satira_gecen_program
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        int charNumber = 0;
        private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            if (charNumber >= 2)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Hey");

                if (charNumber % (2) == 0)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Hey");

                    textBox1.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);                    
                }

                charNumber++;
                MessageBox.Show("Hey");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It never shows the "Hey" message and it never goes to line below when the charNumber is divisible to 2.

But if I make the code `if (charNumber <= 2)` instead of `if (charNumber >= 2)`, it does show the "Hey" message as expected and writes the next characters one line below as expected.

I did not understand the problem.

Comment: Does reading "[How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)" help?

Comment: You only run `charNumber++` if `charNumber>2`. How is it supposed to ever become greater than 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`charNumber` is initialized to 0 and will never be anything other than 0 with the posted code, since the increment is inside the outer if block, which only runs when `charNumber` >= 2. Maybe you want `charNumber++;` outside of that outer if block like this?

```cs
int charNumber = 0;
private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (charNumber>=2)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Hey");

        if (charNumber % (2) == 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Hey");

            textBox1.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);                    
        }
        
        MessageBox.Show("Hey");
    }
    charNumber++;
}
```